# Add VID that contains string to to FTDI driver Info.plist file

Tags: xcode, macos, driver

I'm trying to add a driver for a device to the Info.plist file for FTDI drivers on a MacBook Pro running High Sierra (10.13.2) using Xcode. I have been following instructions here: https://embeddedartistry.com/blog/2017/6/23/osx-getting-pesky-ftdi-debugging-devices-to-work .

An example of a device on the Info.plist file can be found here:

```
    <key>microHAM USB&lt;-&gt;RS-232-RS232</key>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.FTDI.driver.FTDIUSBSerialDriver</string>
        <key>IOClass</key>
        <string>FTDIUSBSerialDriver</string>
        <key>IOProviderClass</key>
        <string>IOUSBInterface</string>
        <key>bConfigurationValue</key>
        <integer>1</integer>
        <key>bInterfaceNumber</key>
        <integer>0</integer>
        <key>idProduct</key>
        <integer>61166</integer>
        <key>idVendor</key>
        <integer>1027</integer>
    </dict>
```

For my device, the idProduct contains a string (the letter 'E'), which means that I can't format it as an integer, like the example here. Is it possible to add VIDs that don't just contain integers to the Info.plist for FTDI drivers, and if so, how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idProduct for your device is still a number, if it contains an 'E' that just means it's formatted as hexadecimal and you need to convert it to decimal to put in the plist.

Google can do hex->decimal conversions, for example if you google "0x10e4 in decimal", it will show you that 4324 is the result.